# Unable to add label using Neo4j Rest API - Error reading as JSON ''

Tags: rest, neo4j

The neo4j rest api throws runtime exception (error reading as JSON '') when trying to add a label.

My current set up

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId> 
    <artifactId>neo4j-rest-graphdb</artifactId> 
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code that tries to create a new node and add a property and label. The runtime exception is thrown when we try to add the label. The rollback is working fine though. It appears that the API is trying to get details for the resource that is not yet created and trying to parse the response.

```
try ( Transaction tx = db.beginTx() ) {
    //create new user
    Node userNode = db.createNode();
    userNode.setProperty( "id", id );
    userNode.addLabel(DynamicLabel.label("GuestUser")); //throws runtime exception
    tx.success();
}
```

Stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading as JSON ''
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.readJson(JsonHelper.java:57)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.jsonToSingleValue(JsonHelper.java:62)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toEntity(RequestResult.java:114)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult.toMap(RequestResult.java:120)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.getData(ExecutingRestAPI.java:501)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.getData(RestAPIFacade.java:179)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestEntity.getStructuralData(RestEntity.java:75)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestNode.labelsPath(RestNode.java:188)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestNode.addLabel(RestNode.java:147)

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2775)
...
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.util.JsonHelper.readJson(JsonHelper.java:55)
... 43 more
```

Has anyone seen this problem so far.

Comment: Does this also happen when you  remove the transaction block?

Comment: No.. there is no exception when the transaction block is removed. It works fine without the transaction block.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem as those "pseudo" transactions only aggregate operations to send them at once at commit.

So you cannot do "read your writes" or make decisions on them.

And the addLabel operation uses the path returned from the structural info of the node which does not yet exist.

Don't think it's worth fixing. If you think so, please raise an issue at https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding/issues

Comment: Hope this can fixed ASAP. There are no real work arounds for this issue. One option is to commit the transaction that creates the new node and open another transaction to add the label. This defeats the purpose of using transactions in the first place, since rolling back the first transaction is not possible once it is committed. Second option is to not use labels and instead use a property entry. This option is also not acceptable since labels are an important and useful feature that I would like to use.